# Illegal character in Jquery near OnClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, syntax, illegal-characters

I've below a `script`-

```
<head>
   <script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.error-load').hide();
        $('#imgLoading').hide();


        $("#BtnLoadMore").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            var lastArticleId = $('#hdnLastArticle').val();
            var sortOrder = $('#<%= hdnSortValue.ClientID  %>').val();
alert(sortOrder);
            $('#imgLoading').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"RowId":"' + lastArticleId + '", "SortOrder":"' +sortOrder + '"}',
                url: "http://blogs-test.com/themes/blogs/vitalvotes/LoadService.aspx/GetNextData",
                dataType: "json",
                success: RenderPagedData,
                error: function (response) {
                    $('.error-load').show();
                    $('#imgLoading').hide();
                }
            });

        });

​        $("#btnMostRecent").click(function(){
           alert("clicked");    
      });

    });
</script>
```

When i run the page in the `console` of `Firefox` it shows the below `err` -

> SyntaxError: illegal character $("#btnMostRecent").click(function(){

[image]

Am i missing something..?

Please help and thanks in advance..!

Comment: can you please share the HTML code too

Comment: In your editor you should enable the option that invisible characters (like tab, space, newline, ...) are shown. Most likely you have had press something like `alt` while pressing the space key. This will result into a invisible space like, but _invalid_ character.

Comment: So what is RenderPagedData in success: tag?

Comment: Most of the people here got it right. There is a strange character in there just before the `$("#btnMostRecent")`. My suggestion is to delete from the previous `;` all the way to the `$` and then press enter. That should remove any weird characters there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
There is a '?' before $("#btnMostRecent").click(function(){ line.

**?**        $("#btnMostRecent").click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
        });

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.error-load').hide();
        $('#imgLoading').hide();


        $("#BtnLoadMore").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            var lastArticleId = $('#hdnLastArticle').val();
            var sortOrder = $('#<%= hdnSortValue.ClientID  %>').val();
            alert(sortOrder);
            $('#imgLoading').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"RowId":"' + lastArticleId + '", "SortOrder":"' +sortOrder + '"}',
                url: "http://blogs-test.com/themes/blogs/vitalvotes/LoadService.aspx/GetNextData",
                dataType: "json",
                success: RenderPagedData,
                error: function (response) {
                    $('.error-load').show();
                    $('#imgLoading').hide();
                }
            });

        });

        $("#btnMostRecent").click(function () {
            alert("clicked");
        });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Answers without any explanation what you have changed and why are not helpful.

Comment: @shriya - Updated, please check...still does not work

Comment: check ur code. there is question mark (?). just paste your code on textpad u can see that :)

Comment: There is not necessarily a `?` in front of it. It depends on the editor (how the editor visualizes invisible or unknown characters).

Comment: r u copied this copied this code from some where? that is why there is a ? mark . i think so

Answer (score 0):

Are you copy and pasted from somewhere the code ? Here is the pic and found the red dot :

[image]

Remove that and should be okay

Comment: @both- the dot means you have an syntax err near to that...FYI i dont have a .(dot) or period(.)

Comment: Probably did't see that character in the code, are you ever try to remove the white space above it

Comment: @Norlihazmey Ghazali there is a question mark before that line.

Comment: paste that code in a text pad u can see that question mark

Comment: ok. copy the two click event function from my code and paste it in yours. then it will work

Comment: One more thing `data: '{"RowId":"' + lastArticleId + '", "SortOrder":"' + sortOrder + '"}',` should be `data: { RowId : lastArticleId, SortOrder : sortOrder },`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and getting the same error you mentioned. Can you replace the following code with your code? I have removed the special character.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.error-load').hide();
        $('#imgLoading').hide();


        $("#BtnLoadMore").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            var lastArticleId = $('#hdnLastArticle').val();
            var sortOrder = $('#<%= hdnSortValue.ClientID  %>').val();
alert(sortOrder);
            $('#imgLoading').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"RowId":"' + lastArticleId + '", "SortOrder":"' +sortOrder + '"}',
                url: "http://blogs-test.com/themes/blogs/vitalvotes/LoadService.aspx/GetNextData",
                dataType: "json",
                success: RenderPagedData,
                error: function (response) {
                    $('.error-load').show();
                    $('#imgLoading').hide();
                }
            });

        });

        $("#btnMostRecent").click(function(){
           alert("clicked");    
      });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have copied the code from a source which supports Unicode encoding, then you would get the error because, `'` and `"` is a single quote (which we use while coding) and `‘` and `“`  are also quotes. If the code is copied from such a source, dont forget to remove the unsupported characters.

> PS. jQuery doesn't support unicode.

To avoid this problem in future, copy the code to notepad (plain text) and then copy from there, and try pasting again to your code editor!!